# how to extract specific data from csv file like"Name", "Address"?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, data-science

```
    Name
4   A-------
5   ---
6   Father Name
7   ------
8   Gender
9   Country of
10  M
11  Oman
12  Identity Number -n?
13  Date of Birth
14  ------------9
15  28.10.1995
16  ----
17  Date of Issue
18  Date of Expiry
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Pls provide a more elaborated sample of your dataframe  in a form of a table

Comment: @Daweo i want to extract specific data from images using OCR, but when the data are extracted ,it is not structured..

Comment: @gtomer i have mentioned the data in form of column i want to structured the data into rows. like "NAME" and the name of person, " Father name" then it show father name,

Answer (score 1):

To extract a specific column from a csv file you can simply use the *iloc* function from the pandas library after reading the initial csv file.

```
dataset = pd.read_csv("path_of_csv")
# Now once you've read the original csv file you can slice along the columns
# to get the desired column (Example: Name, 1st column)
Name = dataset.iloc[:,0]
```

Or if you use an older version of pandas, this just might work:
(Definitely works for pandas version 1.3.5)

```
dataset = pd.read_csv("path_of_csv")
Name = dataset['Name']
```